# XCode 7.3.1 can't find sqlite3.0 lib despite the file being where it says it can't find it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I have a static lib project that has been working fine and had the libsqlite3.0.tbd dylib linked to it. I moved the static lib project into a new UI project and suddenly that lib, and all other libs actually that could be linked to through the UI as .tbd, can not be found by XCode. I thought, okay I've corrupted my static lib project file I'll just create a new static lib project and move files into it. So I tried to create a brand new static lib and link the sqlite3.0 dylib to that before moving any files into it and it too gives this same error message:

> error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.tbd (No such file or directory)

Yet I can go to Terminal and cd to that dir and there's the file.

But the projects won't build.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try going into `Build Settings > Other Linker Flags` and set `-lsqlite3`

Comment: Also, in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/lib/` there are zero `.tdb` files ... they are in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/`